# Oracle SQL date between not showing any data

Tags: sql, oracle, date, between

This is my table:

[image]

I want to get is everything which SESSIONDATE is on JUNE,
I'm using my code:

```
SELECT * FROM CONFERENCESESSION
WHERE SESSIONDATE BETWEEN '01-06-17' AND '30-06-17';
```

Result is empty as I didn't get anything with this code.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [trunc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm) function with 'MONTH' to get June 2017:

```
SELECT * FROM CONFERENCESESSION
WHERE trunc(SESSIONDATE, 'MONTH') = trunc(to_date('06-17','MM-YY'),'MONTH')
```

> The TRUNC (date) function returns date with the time portion of the day truncated to the unit specified by the format model fmt.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM CONFERENCESESSION
WHERE SESSIONDATE BETWEEN to_date('01-06-17','DD-MM-YY') 
AND to_date('30-06-17','DD-MM-YY');
```